# Am I using preposition correctly?

Tags: prepositions

I'm preparing for IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using Grammarly.

In the following sentence,

"shopping malls would be even a better place to spend time at",

the app suggests deleting the last preposition ('at'). Why is it so?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the real issue with this sentence is "even a better place". You really can't phrase it that way. It has to be "an even better place".

Regarding "at" at the end: there's an oft-quoted rule that sentences shouldn't end with prepositions, but really it's one of those rules that needs to be broken quite a lot, especially in speech. What the app wants you to do here is to say "...an even better place at which to spend time". Writing it according to the rule is fine. If you were to speak that way in a regular conversation, native speakers would think you were being very formal.

[It's said that Winston Churchill once ridiculed this rule](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/11/14/churchill-on-prepositions/), saying something like "Ending a sentence with a preposition is the kind of thing *up* with which I will not *put*" (the joke being that this sentence observes the rule, but is a very awkward way of speaking that most people would never use).

Comment: The question’s more about spending time *at* a place vs. spending time *somewhere*, isn’t it? Deleting the ‘at’ would yield ‘shopping malls would be even a better place to spend time’.

Comment: "even a better place" would still not be correct.

Comment: Oh, certainly, but that should be an addendum to explaining the differences between the OP’s example and the Grammarly-recommended one.